# How to create a SQL table inside the project path instead of outside in Azure datalake from databricks?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake, databricks-sql

I am working on a project in which I want to create a SQL table and save it a project path. Here is how my project path looks like this.

```
abfss://dev@xyz.dfs.core.windows.net/hkay/project_name/
```

When I use the below SQL code in databricks, it saves the data in this folder instead of the project path given above. I tried using location {project_path} inside create statement but it failed due to wrong syntax.

```
spark.sql(f"""
  CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE  {database}.table_name
  SELECT * FROM {database}.table_name_temp
  WHERE 1=0
""")
```

This creates a folder in abfss://dev@xyz.dfs.core.windows.net/hkay/ outside the project path which I don't want. Any idea?

**Edit 1:**

This is what I was using. Not sure if the syntax is correct.

```
spark.sql(f"""
  CREATE {database}.table_name
  LOCATION 'abfss://dev@xyz.dfs.core.windows.net/hkay/project_name/'
  SELECT * FROM {database}.table_name_temp
  WHERE 1=0
""")
```

Comment: Please share the code with the location mentioned and the error you got. Your approach to use location is the right one...

Comment: use dbutils to specify the folder or path then create your table and it should work as expected.

Comment: Just added the syntax @rainingdistros

Comment: @hkay, In your code, you are creating SQL table and trying to store it in an abfss location. But from where you are inserting the data? and what does it mean by `WHERE 1=0` in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to create an empty table with the structure as another table, then you need to use slightly different syntax (see [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-using.html)) - note the `AS` clause:

```sql
CREATE database.table_name
  USING delta
  LOCATION 'abfss://dev@xyz.dfs.core.windows.net/hkay/project_name/'
  AS SELECT * FROM database.table_name_temp LIMIT 0
```